# Force TranslateAnimation to be visiable only in view's bound

Tags: android, android-animation

How can I force a `TranslateAnimation` to work in view's bound only? In other words I want to clip `TranslateAnimation` frames by view's bound.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place your view on a parent view just with the same size and position

Comment: yes, your solution works but it causes some overhead AND I don't like overheads at all :)